# What is the best approach to archiving operational data?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a sql server 2012 database which is the backend to an asp.net MVC application, storing customer and order information. This database is accessed under high load and high usage.

I know have a requirement to be able to generate ad hoc reports from the database accessing the same data as the MVC application works with. I am concerned what impact this would have on the database server and the database itself, around locking etc. As such their is a distinction between the data, for the app its operational, but for the reports its more data warehouse oriented.

Therefore I am looking at my options as to the best approach to avoid such.

I am considering creating another database on a different server and archive the data to it using a sql job at regular intervals during the day. Only concern around this is that it would require maintenance and also a dependency to ensure any necessary changes are made to the target database when the source database changes.

What other options opened to me in such a situation and what advice could be given regarding such? What is the best approach to such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to think of your own solution to keep the databases in sync. SQL Server has build in ways to achieve this.

[Database Mirroring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx)

[Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

[Always On Availability Groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510230.aspx)

If you're using Enterprise Edition of SQL Server 2012 then I would look into Always On Availability Groups if not then (Transactional) Replication. Both of these solutions can keep a second read-only and near real-time copy of the database.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve McConell [suggests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) you should make no assumptions about performance. You should just measure it before making any decisions. It is not a wise choice to make design choices without knowing the actual performance overhead. So I would suggest to measure, or simulate the performance overhead before even consider using a complex architecture, because you would not know if it's worth the trouble.

Anyway, I think that your approach is right. I would create a windows service which periodically retrieves the data I need from my database and stores them in my warehouse (the new database). I don't think you would ever find a tool keeping consistency between the two schemas, unless you want one schema to be an exact copy of the other.

I don't  know your exact needs and perhaps my suggestion is an overkill but I would encourage you to consider using an [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) approach in the data warehouse where your reporting data will come from. I have to warn you that these systems are oriented in really big data and advanced reporting needs but perhaps you can take some ideas from them. Since you are familiar with the Microsoft ecosystem, I would suggest using [Business Intelligence Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You could there build an OLAP cube using your normal database as data source and integrate advanced reporting.

Hope I helped.